# Hotlink prevention only for a certain website

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://website.net/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://website.net$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.website.net/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.website.net$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|rar)$ http://website.net/news.php [R,NC]
```

This is what I use at the moment (auto-generated from my cPanel).

Is there a way that I enable this hotlink protection only from a certain website, e.g. `site.com`?

Or another option is to disabe it for certain websites - `trustedsite1.com`, `trustedsite2.com`

Any of those two options suit me well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To block hotlinking from a specific site:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https?://site.com$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|rar)$ http://website.net/news.php [R,NC]
```

To allow from trustedsite1 and trustedsite2, just add additional conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://website.net/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://website.net$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.website.net/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.website.net$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://trustedsite1.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://trustedsite2.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|rar)$ http://website.net/news.php [R,NC]
```